# sudo: elasticsearch-plugin: command not found

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-plugin

i am trying to install zentity 1.8.1- on elasticsearch-7.12.1 however i am getting below error:

I have tried As per the zentity official documentation https://zentity.io/docs/installation/ but no luck.

```
  sudo elasticsearch-plugin install zentity-1.8.1-elasticsearch-7.12.1.zip
```

output / error :

```
sudo: elasticsearch-plugin: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make sure that either;

1. `$ES_HOME` is in your `$PATH`, or
2. that you are in the `$ES_HOME` directory and run `bin/elasticsearch-plugin`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your ES located in the following directory:

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/
```

If it's there you need to run:

```
sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install zentity-1.8.1-elasticsearch-7.12.1.zip
```